# Seaborn: plot dictionary of lists with different colour

Tags: python, dictionary, seaborn

I was wondering, is there a simple way, to plot a dictionary of keys:list of values, using seaborn, possibly each list of values belonging to a key, with different colour.

```
avx = {'A': [8.06390789458573,
      11.350427821200224,
      18.253071171324542], 
      'B': [34.32754544872351,
      26.565496693414225,
      26.565496693414225]}
```

What I was trying to do, but fails:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=avx,
                x=avx.keys(),
                y=avx.values(), 
                palette="deep")
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried yet.

Comment: `sns.swarmplot(data=avx, palette="deep")` should work, also when the lists have different lengths.

Comment: For a "simple" scatter plot, in case the lists have different lengths: `sns.scatterplot(data=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({k: v}) for k, v in avx.items()], axis=1).melt().dropna(),  x='variable', y='value', hue='variable', palette="deep", legend=False)`